# Get javascript to crop printing page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I'm currently using javascript to produce and print (from a toshiba POS printer) a receipt (using the standard:

```
window.print();
```

method) and html, this works fine however the receipt is printed A4 size and leaves a large white space below the content of the receipt. Using quite a bit of paper unnecessarily. Is there any way I can crop the size of the page printed to the height of the content?

Comment: If it's printing A4, it might be your printer settings

Comment: This is really a CSS problem, not a JavaScript problem.  And be warned that browser support of CSS print styles is abominable (at best).